# How to get data from mongodb to put in an option?

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

I am creating a dashboard table for displaying the saved data in mongoDB. I already have a table and display all the data in the table, now what I want to achieve is to create a `select` element above the database table the `select` element should contains all the available dates from mongodb. For example I have 20 same dates of `05/25/2019` and 10 same dates of `05/26/2019` and 30 same dates of `05/29/2019` I want to display only three options which the dates said above in the `select` element. and if another dates is added in the database that should also be displayed on the `option` too.

I tried doing on the same thing that I did on the table to my select options but of course like the data in the table it display all the same date so I had like 60 options where `30` were same dates of  `05/29/2019` and `10` were same dates of `05/26/2019` and `20` were the same dates of `05/25/2019`

this is my `index.js`

```
var express = require("express"),
app = express(),
bodyparser = require("body-parser"),
mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/sample", {useNewUrlParser: true});
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use('/views', express.static('views'));

var nameSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  route : String,
  origin : String,
  destination : String,
  estimatedTimeOfArrival : String,
  date : String,
  time : String
},{
    collection : 'log'
}) 

  var User = mongoose.model("User", nameSchema);

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
res.render("index",{ details: null })
})


app.get("/getdetails", function (req, res) {   
    User.find({}, function (err, allDetails) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        res.render("index", { details: allDetails })
    }
});
});

app.listen(1412, "localhost", function () {
console.log("server has started at " + 1412);
})
```

this is my `index.ejs`

```
<div  class="tableFixHead">
                            <% if(details!=null) { %>
                        <table  id="myTable" >
                            <thead>
                                <tr class="header" style=" color: white !important;font-weight:bold;">
                                    <th scope="col">Route</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Origin </th>
                                    <th scope="col">Destination</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Estimated Time of Arrival </th>
                                    <th scope="col">Date </th>
                                    <th scope="col">Time</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <% details.forEach(function(item){ %>
                            <tbody id="myTable" style="color:black;">     
                                <tr>
                                    <td><%= item.route%></td>
                                    <td><%= item.origin %></td>
                                    <td><%= item.destination%></td>
                                    <td><%= item.estimatedTimeOfArrival %></td>
                                    <td><%= item.date%></td>
                                    <td><%= item.time%></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                            <% }) %>
                        </table>
                        <% } %>
                    </div>
```

and a sample html data https://jsfiddle.net/indefinite/3yzvemcg/2/

The `dates` are coming from a web app. so after the user submit the form from the app it will saved in my mongoDB and right now I have many data in database and many are sent on the same dates and what I want to achieve is to get the all the dates saved in the database and if the some dates are the same it will only display as one and  `option` will be added if the dates were added too in the database. I'm really new at this so thank you in advanced.

Comment: How about maintaining a separate lookup table in mongoDB which dates are already in `name` table so that you only have to look at that lookup table?

Comment: @cadenzah sorry I'm new at this. You mean I manually add dates?

Comment: Just like you have `User` model to save data for users, maintain a model, let's say, `Date` model and every time you add a new user in `User` model, you also check `Date` model and see if the date for that new user is already in the `Date` model. This may seem little inefficient as you have check the `Date` model every time you add a new user, but I guess this will do what you want.

Comment: @cadenzah The `dates` are coming from a web app. so after the user submit the form from the app it will saved in my mongoDB and right now I have many data in database and many are sent on the same dates and what I want to achieve is to get the all the dates saved in the database and if the some dates are the same it will only display as one and not all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well your problem, you want to find all distinct dates from your `User` model. Maybe your solution is the `distinct` mongoose option.
Try this in your index.js:

```
User.find().distinct('date', function(err, dates) {
    // dates are an array of all distinct dates.
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        res.render("index", { dates: dates })
    }
});
```

And in your ejs file add this.

```
// display select only when 'dates' array is defined.
<% if (locals.dates) { %> 
    <select name="date" id="dates">
    <% dates.forEach(function(date){ %>
        <option><%= date %></option>
    <% }) %>
    </select>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Hello thank you for the respond, after trying your code I get an error of `dates is not defined` pointing in `<% dates.forEach(function(date){ %>` and I see that it shows the dates but only in the console

Comment: I updated my answer, i added locals object to display the `dates` select only when dates array is defined.

Comment: In which get method do you use it?

Comment: Hello I'm really sorry, but what do you mean by that?

Comment: the code i answered you (`User.find().distinct...`), where did you place it?

Comment: `app.get("/")` or `app.get("/getdetails")`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194228/discussion-between-indefinite-and-dimitris-tseggenes).